# Trying to Center Text, but There is a Blank Space at the End Throwing Everything Slightly Off

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a piece of text on a basic website I'm making with html and CSS; however, any text that I add to the site has a small amount of blank space at the end, and I can't figure out how to get rid of it. I understand this is a small problem and the text is only slightly off center. Regardless, any suggestions on how to fix this would be appreciated.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8"/>
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv = "X-UA-Compatible" content = "ie=edge">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hellooo</p>
        <p>Hellooo</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

p {
    font-size: 10vh;
    letter-spacing: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Image of the site on an iPhone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMoIs.png

Comment: Do you mean the result of `letter-spacing: 12px;` ?

Comment: Oh, that is what’s causing it, how can I remove the space after the last letter.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. Thanks